# React-hook-form useWatch не берет значения из defaultValues формы

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Есть форма из чекбоксов, их состояние храню в контексте и использую в качестве defaultValues.

```
const [selectedTags, setSelectedTags] = useDashboardStoreProvider((store) => store.tagsList);

const form = useForm({defaultValues: selectedTags});
const watcher = useWatch(form)
```

В другой компоненте, получаю состояние и пытаюсь изменить его.

```
 const handleDeleteTag = (tag: string) => {
 const newTagsList: ITagsListContext = {
        ...tagsList,
        selectedTags: {
            ...tagsList.selectedTags,
            [tag]: false
        }
    }
setTagsList({tagsList: newTagsList})
```

Обновленное состояние приходит в defaultValues, но watcher почему-то держит старое состояние и соответственно обратно выставляет его в форму.
То есть у меня watcher игнорирует defaultValues, но при прямом взаимодействии с формой все работает как надо.